# Having trouble with nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having some trouble with this part of nested dictionaries. I have tried a bunch of different things but I keep getting this error:

```
complete_dict[county]['price'] = int(item.get(average_price))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here are the instructions and the code I have so far.

```
    # Finally you will find how much the housing prices have changed in each county.
    # You can get this number by finding the difference between the average home price
    # in April 1996 and the average home price in April 2015.
    # The values should mostly be positive since home prices have increased since 1996.
    # We are expecting to see float values.

    # todo Put code here to find the housing prices.
    for item in home_data:
        price = int(item.get('Home Price', 0))
        county = item.get('county')
    if county in complete_dict:
       price1 = complete_dict[county].get('price', 0)
       average_price = price1-price
       complete_dict[county]['price'] = int(item.get(average_price))
    else:
       complete_dict[county] = {'price': int(price)}
```

Here are more instructions about what complete_dict is:
Dictionary Creation
# Make a dictionary using county name as the key.
# From the hospital dataset you will want to add all of the total_licensed_beds in a county.
# From the COVID dataset you will want to add active cases.
# From the Housing dataset you will want the difference between the housing prices (2015 - 1996).
# Your data structure will look like this:
# {'county1': {'beds': [1], 'cases': [2], 'housing': [3]}, 'county2': {'beds': [1], 'cases': [2], 'housing': [3]}}

Comment: Could you please tell us what complete_dict is?

Comment: What are you expecting `item.get(average_price)` to be equal to? Why?

Comment: `item.get(average_price)` returns `None` which means that there's no such as key in dictionary. You can pass default return value as second argument of `dict.get()`.

Comment: Oh yes! complete_dict is the dictionary with the different values coming from the JSON file. So we got the API data from a website and then we are supposed create a dictionary.

Comment: No, we don't care where the data comes from; we want to see *what the data actually looks like*.

Comment: The data structure will look like this, is that what you mean? {'county1': {'beds': [1], 'cases': [2], 'housing': [3]}, 'county2': {'beds': [1], 'cases': [2], 'housing': [3]}}